# Why ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers} not populated in application-test.yaml although i see the spring.embedded.kafka.brokers existing?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

We're using `@EmbeddedKafka`, and in `application-test.yml` we have

```
kafka:
  confluentBootstrapAddress: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
```

I can see that `confluentBootstrapAddress` is `null`.

However, if in debug mode i check this

```
this.resolveEmbeddedValue("${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}") = "127.0.0.1:51020"
```

then i can see that the value exists, and that the embedded Kafka was indeed started.

What could be the issue? A lifecycle / moment mismatch between the moment that `application.yml` is evaluated and when the embedded broker is started?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was an error in the test setup that was using `@Profile` instead of `@ActiveProfiles`. Changing that to `ActiveProfiles` made that Spring Test take into account the `"spring-profile.properties"`.